# Attempting to loop through an ArrayList to find duplicates, if statement never seems to return true

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, conditional-statements

I'm trying to loop through an ArrayList of Card objects to find duplicate cards. The if statement is meant to compare two different objects in the list and simply set a Boolean to true if a duplicate is found.

```
public boolean hasDuplicate() {
    boolean isDupe = false;


    for(int a = 0; a < pack.size(); a++){

        for(int b = a + 1; b < pack.size(); b++){

            if (pack.get(a).equals(pack.get(b))){

                isDupe = true;
            }
        }
    }       
    return isDupe;
}
```

This is what I've been using to test it.

```
public void testDuplicate(){
    if (pc.hasDuplicate() == true){
        System.out.println("There is a dupe");
    }
    if (pc.hasDuplicate() == false){
        System.out.println("No Dupe");
    }
}
```

It always outputs "No Dupe" as the conditional statement that switches the Boolean never fires.

Any help (read: pointing out my glaring mistakes) would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How does your Card object implement equals? How do you initialise your list of card objects?

Comment: You haven't overridden `equals(Object)` in your `Card` object. Also, remove all occurrences of  `== true` and replace all  `x == false` with `!x`. Further, replace `if (cond) action1; if (!cond) action2;` with `if (cond) action1; else action2;`

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.  [Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

If you are comparing two different object you need to implement `equlas()` method in your class, you have to implement `equals()` method in `Card` class.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that in java objects are **by default** compared **by reference**. Often you want to compare them **by value** and they are referred as value classes.

To get a value class you need to overwrite implementation of equals so that it is:

1) **Reflexive** : Object must be equal to itself.

2) **Symmetric** : if a.equals(b) is true then b.equals(a) must be true.

3) **Transitive** : if a.equals(b) is true and b.equals(c) is true then c.equals(a) must be true.

4) **Consistent** : multiple invocation of equals() method must result same value until any of properties are modified. So if two objects are equals in Java they will remain equals until any of there property is modified.

5) **Null comparison** : comparing any object to null must be false and should not result in NullPointerException. For example a.equals(null) must be false, passing unknown object, which could be null,  to equals in Java is is actually a Java coding best practice to avoid NullPointerException in Java.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html#ixzz3PYg2fWPM
(or read Effective Java: Joshua Bloch)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Implement `equals()` properly for `Card`
- Implement `hashCode()` properly for `Card`, such that value is based on the same fields as were compared in `equals()`

Then throw away the loops and code this:

```
public boolean hasDuplicate() {
    return new HashSet<Card>(pack).size() == pack.size();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, implementing equals properly through the source menu in Eclipse was enough to get it working.